# Typescript + React: Use props AND (!) destructuring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, destructuring

I know that it´s possible to use destructuring for props in React. However, can I use destructuring **AND** props? So that I have some determined inputs and also some addtional ones that I access via *props*

**Example**

---

This is the expected output. So I can use *name* and *age* directly, and everything else via *props* e.G. *props.lastName;

```
const ExampleComponent : React.FC<{name: string, age:number}> = ({name, age}, props) => {
    // do something
}
```

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: You can use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

Comment: `({name, age, ...props})` uses a rest parameter.

Comment: @Andy  and what if I want to use additionally React.FC for TypeScript? As you can see in the edited example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
const ExampleComponent: React.FC<{ name: string; age: number }> = ({
  name,
  age,
  ...props
}) => {
  // do something
};
```

This works with typescript too. You can just type check name and age.

Comment: But how do you typecheck name and age in this example? The way I found is with React.FC (as stated in my example)

Comment: You do it just like your example. just change argument part from ({name, age}, props) to ({name, age, ...props})

Comment: I get then the following error **"Property 'lastName' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2339)"**

Comment: I'm not sure why you get that error. But try adding `[key: string]: any;` to your Props type and see if it works.